# How to obtain a condition as an user input in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, input

Below is a code that I've being working on recently and it's aim is to obtain a condition (arithmetic or comparison) from the user as an input and check if it's legitimate for a set of pre-defined values.

The problem being that I can't find a way to convert the string input.

[image]

Below is what I want but with user input:

[image]

PS: I'm vastly inexperience :(.

I tried playing with the 'operator' module but still wasn't able to get anything.

[image]

The code would seem junky and I apologize for the mistakes in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use `eval()` function in python **to convert your condition that is in format of string into the boolean condition** which will act according to what you want, here is a code sample:

```
# sample of using eval()
a, b = 0, 2
str_condition = "a+b > 0" # in the string format

# convert it to boolean condition format
print(eval(str_condition)) # answer: True
```

Apply it with your user's input condition

```
a = 5
b = 9

str_condition = input('enter condition: ')
print('convert string to boolean condition:',str_condition)
print('result from using eval:', eval(str_condition))
```

the result of using `eval()` is

```
enter condition: a+b == 14
convert string to boolean condition: a+b == 14
result from using eval: True
```

try to use it with your code, hope this help !

Comment: Thanks for the help @xty ! It works great alone and integrated. Have a nice day :)

Comment: You're welcome, have a nice day too :)